# How to set a class variable at compile time in D?

Tags: d

How would I set this PREFIX value at compile time? Even better would be using an array/tuple and append to PREFIX.

```
class CarbNamespace {

  //This is the variable I'd like to set
  enum/Tuple PREFIX;

  void initPrefix(string _PR)(){
     //I would like to set the variable PREFIX variable to _PR(or some string modification)
     PREFIX = _PR; ??
  }


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question and details don't line up in my head.

"How to set a class variable at compile time in D?"

You can't. As Adam points out from Kyle's answer, you can create an object at compile time which in effect would set the variables at compile time; I doubt that is your interest.

> //This is the variable I'd like to set
>
> enum/Tuple PREFIX;"

Well, setting it at compile time certainly can be done if it is an enum (which is not a type)

```
class CarbNamespace {
  //This is the variable I'd like to set
  enum PREFIX = giveMeValue();
}

auto giveMeValue() {
  return "text";
}
```

But this isn't a class variable, it is just an enum constant with a class namespace, possibly what you want.

A class doesn't exist until the module is loaded at run-time. This means you'll need to set the variable on module load, this is done with a module constructor (static this).

```
static this() {
  CarbNamespace.PREFIX = giveMeValue();
}

class CarbNamespace {
  //This is the variable I'd like to set
  static string PREFIX;
}

string giveMeValue() {
  return "text";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely sure if I understand your question, but try this:

```js
class CarbNamespace
{
    static string[] PREFIX = ["test1_", "test2_"];

    void appendToPrefix(string _PR)
    {
        PREFIX ~= _PR;
    }
}

void main()
{
    import std.stdio : writeln;
    CarbNamespace ns = new CarbNamespace();
    writeln(ns.PREFIX);
    ns.appendToPrefix("test3_");
    writeln(ns.PREFIX);
}
```

Comment: and if you do `enum CarbNamespace ns = new CarbNamespace();` it should be able to build it at compile time. But, in general, all compile time variables are immutable, set once then cannot change. Appending to a compile time array, except inside the setter function on the first call, is impossible.